# Install of OroCRM on CentOS 8 Stream Fails

Tags: orocrm

Running the line:

`php bin/console oro:install --env=prod --timeout=2000`

Causes the following output:

| ERROR | Database connection is not configured

The database connection IS configured in `config/parameters.yml` and the credentials have been tested and are valid.

Centos 8 Stream is a basic install with only Apache 2.4x, PHP 8.1 and MySQL 8.1.3 the additional components install.

SELinux is enabled. Booleans have been set for httpd_ and mysql_ parameters.

Why doesn't the DB connection succeed?  Is there a log to show what it can't achieve?

Comment: After changing parameters.yml, it is required to clear the application cache by running `rm -rf var/cache/*`, otherwise changes are not considered. Most likely, it's the reason for the issue.

Comment: it seems this question is the same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71218654/database-connection-not-configured-oro-crm/71269773

Answer (score 0):

For some reason parameters.yml is parsed incorrectly. Use these lines instead:

```
env(ORO_DB_HOST): "localhost"
env(ORO_DB_PORT): "3306"
env(ORO_DB_NAME): db_name
env(ORO_DB_USER): db_user
env(ORO_DB_PASSWORD): "SecretPassword"
env(ORO_DB_VERSION): "8.1.3"
```